# Laravel 5 - moving uploaded file with german characters

Tags: filenames, laravel-5

Is there a way to move uploaded file and name it with german characters?

I have a form where user inputs his name and surname and adds a file.
File is uploaded correctly and all input fields are saved in mysql database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $file_name = $request->input('name_surname') . '_' . $request->input('month') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file('file')->move('uploads', $file_name);
    $this->report->create(array('name_surname' => $request->input('name_surname'),
                                'file_name' => $file_name,
                                'ini_file_name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                                'month' => $request->input('month'),
                                'sum' => $request->input('sum')));

    return redirect('/');
}
```

When I open my 'uploads' folder, file name looks like this:

```
GĂĽnter BaumgĂ¤rtner_Februar 2015.pdf
```

dd($file_name); shows this:

```
"Günter Baumgärtner_Februar 2015.pdf"
```

MySQL record looks like this:

```
id | name_surname       | month        | sum | file_name                           | ini_file_name
39 | Günter Baumgärtner | Februar 2015 | 200 | Günter Baumgärtner_Februar 2015.pdf | report-11-02-2015_01-36.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your system encoding. Is your machine running Linux?

If yes, check your server LANG enviromental variable: at command prompt type `locale` and look at a line starting with `LANG=`. If it is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` (or any other value ending with `.UTF-8`) then renaming/creating files with german characters should work. In my environment (`LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8`) it works, my Laravel app created a file named `Günter_Baumgärtner.csv`.
If your LANG is set to non-UTF-8 value, then should change it, but the way how to do it depends on your Linux distribution.

Comment: It is system encoding problem. I'm running windows 8.1 but now I moved the application to vps server that runs ubuntu. It saves the file just like it should. Thx